# Get input field data by clicking on the button and get value under the button in p element in angular7

Tags: angular, input, input-field

I am new in angular and my sir give me the exercise to get input field data in p element by clicking on a button using angular 7.I do so much attempts using some functions (onClick,onClickSubmit,myFunction) but i failed in every attempt.I think i got problem in data-binding / event-binding.Please help me to sort out this problem.

[app.component.html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1OWQ.jpg)

[app.component.ts file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MT7uy.jpg)

Comment: you should use [ngModel] property on your input element, for more information try this tutorial https://angular.io/start

Comment: `<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" name="name"><p>{{ name}}</p>`

Comment: Show what you have tried so far

Comment: I have edit my post now see again and sort out my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" name="name">
<br>
<br>
<button (click)="show = true">Show</button>
<p *ngIf="show">{{name}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be two solutions (both you can find [here working link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nqoyfw)) for this.

1. Dynamic update: As soon as you enter in text box should be reflected in paragraph also.
   solution: This can be achieved by using ngModel two way data binding. in this case no 
   button need to update paragraph.
2. Paragraph should take the input text only when you submit or click on button.

   [Check this link, you can play with it by changing code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nqoyfw)

Hope this helps. All the best. Keep Learning.